# Design pattern for switching product list layout

Tags: reactjs, react-native, design-patterns

### What I want

I want to render a **product list** in three formats:

- `stacked vertically (default)`
- `horizontal (scroll)`
- `grid`

PS: `mosaic` is not another format, it is simply a list whose item's content is rendered vertically(column) instead of horizontal(row).

The idea is to use the same component(s) to support all formats(DRY), here the layouts that I want to implement:

[image]

### What I have

#### ProductList

Responsible for rendering a list of products. This component decide how to be rederized the list, in `vertical (default)`, `horizontal (scroll)`, or `grid` mode.

```js
// ProductList.js

import React from 'react'
import {Dimensions, FlatList, View} from 'react-native'

// I'm using typescript, for the purpose of simplicity I don't put all the types
// in the code. Only the ones that define what each property of the component does.
export type ProductListProps = {
  /**
   * Products to display in the list
   */
  products: Product[]
  /**
   * If true, renders items next to each other horizontally instead of stacked
   * vertically.
   */
  showHorizontalList?: boolean
  /**
   * Tell how many columns in Grid.
   */
  numColumns?: number
  /**
   * If true, renders product list item content as column
   */
  productContentAsColumn?: boolean
}

function ProductList({
  products,
  numColumns = 1, 
  showHorizontalList = false,
}) {
  const getLayoutManager = () => {
    const layoutManager = {}
    if (showHorizontalList) {
      layoutManager.horizontal = true
      layoutManager.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
      layoutManager.ItemSeparatorComponent = ProductListItemSeparator
      layoutManager.contentContainerStyle = {padding: 16}
    } else {
      layoutManager.numColumns = numColumns
    }

    return layoutManager
  }

  const renderItemRow = ({item}) => (
    <ProductListItem
      product={item}
      viewContainerStyle={{
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width / numColumns,
      }}
      // change item content direaction from `row` to 'column'
      columnContainerStyle={{flexDirection: 'column'}}
    />
  )

  return (
    <FlatList
      {...getLayoutManager()}
      // Pass a changing value to the `key` prop to update the columns number on the fly
      key={numColumns}
      data={products}
      renderItem={renderItemRow}
    />
  )
}
```

#### ProductListItem

Responsible for rendering list's *item* content. From here, you can modify the `itemContainerStyle` to decide how much space each item should occupy or `contentContainerStyle` to decide whether it should be rendered as a `row(default)` or `column(card)`.

```js
// ProductListItem.js

import {View} from 'react-native'

export type ProductListItemProps = {
  /**
   * Product to display
   */
  product: FeaturedProduct
  /**
   * With this styles you can definde the space can be filled by each item in the list
   */
  itemContainerStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
  /**
   * With this styles you can define if item content should render as `row` or `column`
   */
  itemContentStyle?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}

function ProductListItem({
  product,
  itemContainerStyle = {},
  itemContentStyle = {},
}) {
  return (
    <View style={itemContainerStyle}>
      <View style={[styles.row, itemContentStyle]}>
        // any content can be placed here
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
})
```

### Problem

This nested component design can be really messy(creating ProducListItem inside ProducList). I would like to know if a specific react design pattern can be applied in this case to decouple list(parent) to items(childs), taking into account that the children must access the parent's state/props in order to know what kind of layout should be rendered.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on ReactNative. If it is a web application, your requirement can be satisfied easily by just changing the classname of the container, the layout can be changed by CSS overriding. There are a lot of pure CSS layout switch samples on internet for reference.

Answer (score 1):

> ### Problem
>
> This nested component design can be really messy(creating ProducListItem inside ProducList). **I would like to know if a specific react design pattern can be applied in this case to decouple list(parent) to items(childs), taking into account that the children must access the parent's state/props** in order to know what kind of layout should be rendered.

The pattern that'll do just that is called [Render Prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

You pass a function (usually as `children` prop) from parent to child that tells how to render and the child component provides all necessary data/state for that function expects.

With render-prop pattern your code would look something like this:

```
const SomeParentComponent() => {
  const renderItemRow = ({item, ...rest}) => (
    <ProductListItem
      product={item}
      {...rest}
    />
  )

  return <ProductList>{renderItemRow}</ProductList >
}

function ProductList({
  products,
  numColumns = 1,
  showHorizontalList = false,
  children,
}) {
  const getLayoutManager = () => {
    const layoutManager = {};
    if (showHorizontalList) {
      layoutManager.horizontal = true;
      layoutManager.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
      layoutManager.ItemSeparatorComponent = ProductListItemSeparator;
      layoutManager.contentContainerStyle = { padding: 16 };
    } else {
      layoutManager.numColumns = numColumns;
    }

    return layoutManager;
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      {...getLayoutManager()}
      // Pass a changing value to the `key` prop to update the columns number on the fly
      key={numColumns}
      data={products}
      renderItem={(args) =>
        children({
          ...args,
          viewContainerStyle: {
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width / numColumns,
          },
          columnContainerStyle: { flexDirection: "column" },
        })
      }
    />
  );
}
```

P.S. Since the introduction of hooks, I've observed a new pattern too where a hook takes some data/state and return a component to render.

So the code above can be written as follows with hooks.

```
function useProductItemHook(viewContainerStyle, columnContainerStyle) {
  const renderFunc = React.useCallback((item) => {
    return <ProductListItem
      product={item}
      {...rest}
    />
  }, [viewContainerStyle, columnContainerStyle]);
  return renderFunc;
}


function ProductList() {
  // ... code ...

  const renderProductItem = useProductItemHook(
    {
      width: Dimensions.get("window").width / numColumns,
    },
    { flexDirection: "column" }
  );
  return (
    <FlatList
      {...getLayoutManager()}
      data={products}
      renderItem={({ item }) => renderProductItem(item)}
    />
  );
}
```

This is just a simple demonstration of the possibilities. I'd encourage you to play around and change the implementation to better fit your needs and to optimize.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misinterpreting the question here. So basically what you want to do is render these components in a certain predefined layout without explicitly passing down every prop from the parent?

What you could do in this case is make use of the [React Context API.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

`Context` allows you to distribute props to every component rendered inside the scope of the `Context.Provider`.

For example, if you had something like this:

```js
<MyContext.Provider value={someProps}>
  <Child1 />
  <Child2 />
  <Child3 />
</MyContext.Provider>
```

Than all `Child` component within that `Provider` can access the `someProps` value by calling the `useContext` hook like this:

```
const Child1 = () => {
  const someProps = useContext(MyContext);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

This way you can pass down props easily without having to explicitly "drill" it down to every component. You calculate your desired layout in the parent, pass the props to the `Provider` and each child will know which layout to render without explicitly receiving those props from the parent.

This is very useful for "global" variables like themes or languages as well.

Comment: The specific problem I want to solve is to avoid defining logic that is directly related to the child in the parent, if you can see, in `ProductList`, I am creating the child component `ProductListItem`, what happens if I want to be able to pass a custom `listItem` component?,  This nesting is necesary because certain parent's properties as `numColumns` define certain behaviors in child like how much space should fill... its clear my explanation? maybe [compound components](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks/) could be a solution...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem to solve with a strategy design pattern. Before we move forward, I only have a little background with react. So I have put in place a good effort from my side. But the purpose is to provide the concept of the strategy design pattern here.

To start with, I assume a patent component. This has mostly the logic to choose the view type and the data to be rendered. The control then flows to the `DisplayList` component that wraps the displaying of the list according to view.

```
function Sample() {
  const list = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]; // list to display

  // The view selection
  const [selectedView, setSelectedView] = useState(() => HorizontalView);

  // Set the view (can use some other way to set this)
  // I have considered only 2 views, easily extendable for more
  const toggleView = () => {
    if (selectedView === HorizontalView) setSelectedView(() => VerticalView);
    else setSelectedView(() => HorizontalView);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleView}>Toggle View</button>
      <DisplayList list={list} view={selectedView} />
    </div>
  );
}

// Wrapper component (can be inlined if not needed):
function DisplayList({ list, view = HorizontalView }) {
  return <div>{view({ list })}</div>;
}
```

Finally, here is how the individual view components would look like:

```
function HorizontalView({ list }) {
  const view = (element) => {
    return <li>{element}</li>;
  };

  return <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>{list.map(view)}</ul>;
}


function VerticalView({ list }) {
  const view = (element) => {
    return <li style={{ display: "inline", paddingRight: 10 }}>{element}</li>;
  };

  return <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>{list.map(view)}</ul>;
}
```

Remember, this will only work when the component definitions are same across all view components. Like, both views here take object with list(list as prop) param. If anyone changes the params, that has to be considered by other one.

Code sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-bird-3qp28